# Standard hash function of Linux

Tags: hash, sha-512

So I went through my `/etc/shadow` file in Linux and discovered that my passwords were stored in [SHA-512-based crypt ('sha512crypt') mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Versioning_history), so SHA-512. But why? I mean SHA-512 is not even a secure password hashing function. Why not bcrypt or Argon2 or scrypt ....
And how much iteration does this hash even have?

PS: Does `$2$` "Blowfish" mean bcrypt ? And if yes, then why do they use the name of the block cipher?

Comment: Regarding "Does \$2 "blowfish" mean bcrypt?" bcrypt is based on the blowfish cipher, so that may be why you are seeing $2 denoted as blowfish.

Comment: SHA512crypt is not plain sha512. It's a salted iterated scheme with security comparable to PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA2. From what I heard the construction is even uglier than PBKDF2 (no small feat), but I didn't verify that part.

Comment: What CodesInChaos is really saying is that the indicated hash probably is a *configuration parameter* for the password hashing function used. This is similar of specifying the hash at the end of the TLS ciphersuites that configures the HMAC function (PRF) used. For PBKDF2 it actually goes a bit deeper: the hash configures the HMAC which is then used within the password function.

Comment: @CodesInChaos my goodness were you right. It is uglier and more nonsense-filled than I ever thought possible. Like a n00b throwing a bunch of random operations together hoping that "impossible to implement securely" means secure! See https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt for the spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though not my normal recommendation, the SHA-512-based password hash as implemented in Linux is a fine password hashing algorithm.  It is based on a well-understood cryptographically secure hash (SHA-512). It has a significant size salt and configurable number of rounds (default 5000). I would not feel insecure with such a hashing algorithm.

`$2$` is indeed bcrypt, but note there are several variants around sometimes marked 2a or 2b and sometimes not marked. So, though bcrypt is considered very secure if you need a standard password hashing function, you need to be careful when choosing bcrypt.

Comment: how secure is bcrypt comparde to the Implementation of sha512 in Linux ?

Comment: Both are entirely uncrackable using any public cryptanalytic texhnique. Brute force depends on security paramater for each but is generally unfeasable for reasonably secure passwords. It's difficult to compare.

Comment: @RichardR.Matthews Bcrypt is significantly stronger against GPU based attackers.